# Why is this code on array of structures working?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

This code on array of structures is working but according to my understanding it shoudn't.
Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    struct virus {
        char signature[25];
        char status[20];
        int size;
    } v[2] = {
        "Yankee Doodle", "Deadly", 1813,
        "Dark Avenger", "Killer", 1795
    };

    for(int i=0;i<=1;i++) {
        printf("%s %s\n", &v[i].signature, &v[i].status);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

According to me, when we try to access the members of a structure using the address of an instance of the structure, we must use the `->` operator rather than the `.` operator. I know that we do it only in case a pointer,but as far as I know, array is functionally equivalent to a pointer. Please help me where I am going wrong with my concepts. And pardon my silly question, because I am just a beginner.

Comment: a[b] is equivalent with (*(a+b)), dereference has already happened in the [] operator

Comment: Arrays are not equivalent to pointers. They are often implicitly converted to pointers when used in expressions that work on rvalues (like `operator[]`) but most importantly have a different size (check `sizeof`)

Comment: but I am using &a[b] to access the elements,and i guess &a[b] is equivalent to a+b,which is an address. So, why is **.** still working? I am confused! :)

Comment: . has higher precedence than &

Comment: Ok now you lost me! :P

Comment: @sp2danny:can you give me a link to any article which I can read to understand it? Thank you! :)

Comment: there are many good answers below, with links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should not according to [Operator Precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm). `[]` has higher precedence than `.`, and `.` has higher precedence than `&`. So `&v[i].signature` is equivalent to `& ( (v[i]).signature)`. So first the *ith* item is taken from `v`, then it's `signature` member is accessed, which is a character array, and then `&` is applied which gives the address of the character array.

It works in VS, but this is not standard behavior.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really work. You probably expected `&v[i].signature` to be `(&v[i]).signature` (which should have been `(&v[i])->signature`), but it's actually `&(v[i].signature)`, of type `char (*)[25]`. If the program still produces the expected output, then that's purely by chance.

GCC would have told you this even without `-Wall`:

```
$ gcc -c a.c
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:18:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[25]’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%s %s\n",&v[i].signature,&v[i].status);
         ^
a.c:18:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working because:

```
&v[i].signature == &v[i] == v->signature
(&v).signature == v->signature
```

You have taken the address using `&` and dereferenced using `[]`.